# Is it possible to use Variadic Parameters within Closures?

Tags: swift, parameters, functional-programming, closures, variadic

<sup>Refurbished Question</sup>

## **Swift: Combining the use of Variadic Parameters with Closures**

---

Is it possible to make a closure using variadic parameters?

```
func this(_ hello: (Int...) -> ()) {}
func that(_ yeah: Int...) {}
```

Here's what works: `this(that)`

Here's what didn't work:
`this { foo in }`, `this { _ in }`, `this { }`

---

I'm getting this error:

`Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type '(Int...) -> ()'`

---

I even went so far as to change all `Int...` to `Void...`

I'm got the same results

<sup><sub>With the additional warning of
`When calling this function in Swift 4 or later, you must pass a '()' tuple; did you mean for the input type to be '()'? Replace '(Void...)' with '()'` However, replacing Void... with ()... did the trick</sub></sup>

---

## Simplified Problem

---

```
let _: (()...) -> () = { _ in }
```

Causes this error:
`Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to specified type '(()...) -> ()'`

Is it possible to work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the type in the closure:

```
this { (foo: Int...) in }
```

The type-inference engine isn't quite powerful enough to figure out this case. I suspect it's related to [SR-6030](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6030?jql=text%20~%20%22variadic%20closure%22).